# qt qml QListview updating slow

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt-quick, qstringlist

I'm updating the qml Listview from c++ like;

in main.cpp;

```
listeci frmlisteci;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("listeElemanlar", &frmlisteci.listeElemanlar);
```

in Liste.qml;

```
        ListView{
            id: listeciElemanlar
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: listeElemanlar
            delegate: Text{
                text: display
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignBottom
                width : parent.width
                color: textRengi
                font.pointSize: 30
                leftPadding: 20
            }}
```

in listeci.h;

```
public:
    QStringListModel listeElemanlar;
private:
    QStringList userAyarlari;
```

in listeci.cpp;

```
listeci::listeci(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

    // Kullanıcı ayarları elemanları
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 01");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 02");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 03");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 04");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 05");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 06");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 07");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 08");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 09");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 10");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 11");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 12");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 13");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 14");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 15");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 16");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 17");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 18");
    userAyarlari.append("Kullanıcı ayarı 19");
}
void listeci::listeGuncelle()
{
    listeElemanlar.setStringList(userAyarlari);
}
```

with these lines, I can successfully create a list and show on qml Listview, when I clicked on a button on qml side by calling

```
frmlisteci.listeGuncelle()
```

But when I do this procedure after a mount,( we can say refreshing the list) the code becoming slow, and waiting on this line:

```
listeElemanlar.setStringList(userAyarlari);
```

What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem is causing by stackview....

I'm navigating between the pages by stackview.pop. 
I changed the pop to replace and the problem solved....